# Filter array objects by have a property or not in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array, all objects has property "settings".

I want to get all objects that doesn't contains settings.settingA.

Are there anyway to do that without using loop?

Edit:

I have an array of Profile objects.
Profile object has many properties, one of them is:

```
@property (nonatomic) ProfileSettings *settings;
```

ProfileSettings object has some property:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *settingA;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *settingB;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *settingC;
```

Each Profile can has ProfileSettings with some (not all) settings.

Comment: what kind of thing is `settings`?  Is it a string?  I'm wondering if this might be a job for Predicates?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Settings is an object

Comment: You will get much better responses to your question if you [edit] your question to include relevant code showing what you have and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Maybe use respondsToSelector

Answer (score 0):

> Are there anyway to do that without using loop?

Yes.

Your statement suggests you know how to test an individual object to determine whether you wish to include or exclude it, just that you do not wish to write this test in a loop. So:

1. Use [`filterArrayUsingPredicate:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1411033-filteredarrayusingpredicate?language=objc) to process the array as a whole;
2. Use [`predicateWithBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate/1416182-predicatewithblock?language=objc) to create a predicate with a block; and
3. Write your logic to test an object in the block. The block will be passed an object from your array and must return a `BOOL` indicating whether to keep include (`YES`) it or not in the result.

HTH